# Animated "hamburger" border issue

Tags: mmenu

I have managed to include the animated Hamburger but when I click on it a blue border appears. I have been unable to override this behavior....

I have tried playing with the css on my site to no avail.

Many thanks

Stephen

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the button css instead of the hamburger class.

If you're using `<button>` instead of `<div>`, the `<button>` css can have a `:focus` outline on it.

Try changing the global button css property to:

```
button:focus {
     outline:none;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that works. Now why didn't I think of that :-(